# Connecting data in sharded environment

Tags: database, architecture, sharding

Let's assume that there is a system that stores users and users can follow each other. Now let's assume that data is sharded in multiple databases by continent.
What happens when a user from North America follows another user from Europe?
How can this problem be approached using RDBMS(Postgres), a graph database (Neo4j), or document database (MongoDB)?

Comment: It depends what you need to do with this data. Is this for a real-time notification system or to perform analytics?

Comment: Something like a real-time notification system

Comment: I would use none of the above technologies but rather look at message queues. Each user is a queue and they can register for events from other users' queues.